# Restrict TextBoxField to accept only numeric values in BlackBerry

Tags: regex, blackberry, java-me

How can I restrict a TextBoxField in BlackBerry to accept only numeric values . I'm new to BB world and would like to know if there is any control like a NumericTextbox in asp.net that I can use with BB? Also from what I read through some blogs and documents , regex is not supported in BB. So how can I achieve this without Regex?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [BasicEditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html), or any of it's subclasses, include the [FILTER_NUMERIC](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#FILTER_NUMERIC) in the style parameter of the constructor:

```
BasicEditField numericField = new BasicEditField(FILTER_NUMERIC);
```

For more on using text filters see [this article](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2010/12/fun-with-text-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this in javascript

```
<script language=Javascript>
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
</script>

<html> 
    <body>
        <form action="url" method="get/post">
            <input id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```